# How to set up Paypal Smart Buttons with Flask?

Tags: flask, paypal

I already did a server-side setup for Paypal Payments. I get the product price from the Html form and then creates a payment with **paypalrestsdk module**. Important Chunk of code from the whole system is here:-

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
        "intent": "sale",
        # Set payment method
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        # Set redirect URLs
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": url_for('after_payment_done_2_sol', hash_id=hash_id, user_id=current_user.user_id, _external=True),
            "cancel_url": url_for('topup', _external=True)
        },
        # Set transaction object
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "total": query.total_price,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "description": f"Payment Method for paying {query.total_price} for Top Up"
        }]
    })
    if payment.create():
        print('Payment "{}" created successfully'.format(payment.id))
        for link in payment.links:
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                redirect_url = str(link.href)
                print('Redirect for approval: {}'.format(redirect_url))
                return redirect(redirect_url)
```

So this will create a link to "Pay X Amount via Paypal". But i want to integrate smart Buttons like here
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server. Now here there is a codeblocks like:

```
 <script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({
        // How Does this work?????????????????????
        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                return data.orderID;
            });
        },
        // ???????????????????????????????????????? How does this Work?????
        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                method: 'post'
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(details) {
                // Show a success message to the buyer
                alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

So here **how does onAprrove and createOrder Works? And how should i set up my route in flask?** Any help Please!

Answer (score 0):

That is a server-side integration, so  `/demo/....` needs to be replaced with URLs that will trigger server-side code, on your webserver.

If you want javascript for a client-side integration, use https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: thanks mate! But what should i return from the server on fetch createOrder? and what should i return or pass in onApprove? can you please write in bit details on how those two things will work with server side? Just the procedures,mate.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

When you set up the transaction, return an orderID.

onApprove should call server code that captures an orderID and returns success/failure